# Trouble coding for receiving and parsing MMS on Android?

Tags: android-mms

I am trying to receive MMS through my client's messaging app that's in development. One major issue that I am facing is that I am unable to test in India as service providers here are using legacy system of sending MMS. What I mean is while using default messaging app, when I send MMS from one phone to another, I don't receive the message itself, instead I get the link to portal of my service provider, where I have to login with my username and password to see the attachment as well as the text message. Therefore, I am unable to test MMS receiving and the parsing of received binary data on my phone. So, I have to ask if anyone else who has worked on a messaging app before, could provide some guidance on the topic.